# DNS domain configuration on ispconfig3

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I am stuck on configuring blackflow.info for my home server. Please tell me what I am missing. I've tried everything I could find on the web with no result.Below I've added a link to images with my current settings. Will appreciate any help.

[Settings](http://imageshack.us/g/225/screenshot3qw.png/)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe BIND is not running on your server, or port 53 is blocked, maybe you did not configured at your registrar (netart.pl) what your nameserver(s) is (87.204.237.250).

```
PING 87.204.237.250 (87.204.237.250) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 87.204.237.250: icmp_req=1 ttl=242 time=142 ms
```

BUT

```
>dig @87.204.237.250 blackflow.info 

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @87.204.237.250 blackflow.info
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

AND

```
>dig blackflow.info NS
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;blackflow.info.            IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
blackflow.info.     2559    IN  NS  ns1.netart.pl.
blackflow.info.     2559    IN  NS  ns3.netart.pl.
blackflow.info.     2559    IN  NS  ns2.netart.pl.
```